# keep getting 'list index out of range' while list is existing in python

Tags: python, list, indexing, out

I am trying to give the last element of  at @2@ into <last_animal>, then use it to set the if condition. But it only brings me 'list out of index' message. Just in case, I tried to use a deep copy but it gives me the same result.

I want to know how can I fix this problems and why it happens.

Thanks for your help :)

```
import copy
    
animals = list(range(1,101))
new_animals = list()

#This below works fine
print(animals[-1])

for stage in range(1,8):
    if len(animals) <= 13 and len(animals) % 2 == 1:
        del animals[0]
    for number in animals[::2]:
        new_animals.append(number)
        
    print(new_animals)
    print(len(new_animals))
    
    animals = copy.deepcopy(new_animals)

    # @2@ This below is where I keep getting 'index out of range'
    last_animals = animals[-1]

    print(id(animals))
    print(id(new_animals))
    print()
    new_animals = list()
```

Comment: because after some iterations your list is empty

Comment: The problem is you are resetting the new_animals list.i.e, `new_animals = list()` which makes list empty, hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

You are running out of animals as you go through the iteration.
Try this variant of your code and see what happen to the list.
The trick for the debug is to place the `print()` function in a relevant position.

```
import copy
    
animals = list(range(1,101))
new_animals = list()

for _ in range(1,8):
    if len(animals) <= 13 and len(animals) % 2 == 1:
        del animals[0]
    for number in animals[::2]:
        new_animals.append(number)
    animals = copy.deepcopy(new_animals)
    print(animals)
    num_animals = len(animals)
    print(num_animals)
    if num_animals > 0:
        last_animals = animals[-1]

    new_animals = list()
```

The result is like this:

```
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99]
# 50
# [1, 5, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45, 49, 53, 57, 61, 65, 69, 73, 77, 81, 85, 89, 93, 97]
# 25
# [1, 9, 17, 25, 33, 41, 49, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89, 97]
# 13
# [9, 25, 41, 57, 73, 89]
# 6
# [9, 41, 73]
# 3
# [41]
# 1
# []
# 0
```